# Why number of greenlets running is higher than the actual number of created greenlets. 1 additional greenlet is running synchronously

Tags: python, gevent, greenlets

Firstly the following code ideally should run the 3 greenlets synchronously, but instead it runs all 3 greenlets asynchronously. However the strange thing happening is it starts an additional synchronous process for the second greenlet no matter how many greenlets you have. I am not asking this question for an workaround, its just that I want to understand the reason behind this.

```
import gevent
import time

def func(i):
    t = time.time()
    print('func %s started at %s' % (i, t))
    secs = 5
    statement = "after %s secs" % secs
    gevent.sleep(secs)
    print('func %s stopped in %s secs' % (i, (time.time() - t)))

apps = [gevent.Greenlet.spawn(func, i) for i in range(3)]

[app.run() for app in apps]
```

Here's the sample stdout:

```
func 0 started at 1491859273.2895772
func 1 started at 1491859273.2898045
func 2 started at 1491859273.2899446
func 0 stopped in 5.0095603466033936 secs
func 1 started at 1491859278.2993205
func 1 stopped in 5.0163233280181885 secs
func 2 stopped in 5.019707918167114 secs
func 1 stopped in 5.009198188781738 secs
```

How is `func 1 started` happening twice?

Comment: Could you be more explicit about the concrete observations you're actually seeing, and how they differ from what you expect? (Some explanation of *why* you expect the behaviors you do wouldn't hurt either).

Comment: Is my question more clear from the edits above?

Comment: This helps inasmuch as it provides a clear description of what your current behavior is -- but what's still missing is an explanation of why you expect contrary/different behavior.

Comment: `apps` in the module is creating 3 greenlet objects(tasks), but when They are running(`run()`) later, it first make the three tasks run simultaneously, but after the first task is finished it runs the second task again. 
It seems more logical  if 3 tasks have been carried out not 4.

Answer (score 0):

Greenlets are already scheduled for invocation when you invoke `spawn()`. Calling `run()` directly is not part of the publicly documented API, and its effects are undefined. Any description of *why* present behavior is observed, then, would need to go beyond the documented API into implementation details.

Use `gevent.joinall()` to wait for your already-scheduled jobs to complete.

```
apps = [gevent.Greenlet.spawn(func, i) for i in range(3)]
gevent.joinall(apps)
```

correctly yields:

```
func 0 started at 1491921603.6
func 1 started at 1491921603.6
func 2 started at 1491921603.6
func 0 stopped in 5.00121307373 secs
func 1 stopped in 5.00118613243 secs
func 2 stopped in 5.0011780262 secs
```

---

Now, let's dig into that undefined behavior a bit, with the understanding that it's prone to vary release-to-release or system-to-system.

The reason it's specifically Greenlet 1 that's run twice is an accident of when the primary thread of control first cooperatively yields. You can change this behavior by yielding explicitly *before* calling `run()` the first time:

```
print "=== About to spawn greenlets..."
apps = [gevent.Greenlet.spawn(func, i) for i in range(3)]
print "=== All greenlets spawned; yielding..."
gevent.sleep(0)
print "=== Calling a duplicate run() invocation on each"
result = [app.run() for app in apps]
```

With that change, it's greenlet *0* that starts first -- and you'll note that it starts **before** `run()` is ever called at all:

```
=== About to spawn greenlets...
=== All greenlets spawned; yielding...
func 0 started at 1491921486.57
func 1 started at 1491921486.57
func 2 started at 1491921486.57
=== Calling a duplicate run() invocation on each
func 0 started at 1491921486.57
func 0 stopped in 5.00335502625 secs
func 1 stopped in 5.00336790085 secs
func 2 stopped in 5.0033519268 secs
func 0 stopped in 5.0033428669 secs
```